# c++ armadillo - calculating null space

Tags: c++, armadillo

this is my first post here...

Is there any way to calculate a vector in the null space of another vector? I don't need the basis, just one vector in the null space will do.

I already tried using the solve() method -

```
colvec x(3);
x = solve(A,B);
```

where A is a 3x3 matrix of type mat -

```
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
```

and B is the zero vector of type colvec -

```
0
0
0
```

But the program terminates throwing the following error -

```
error: solve(): solution not found
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():
```

I have used the solve() method before and got perfect results, but it doesn't seem to work in this simple case. Is this because the equation has multiple solutions? If so, is there any workaround to this, any other way that I could get a vector in the null space?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit :

I tried the svd(mat U, vec s, mat V, mat X, method = "standard") method and I got the null space of X from the columns of V. I was just wondering if there is any way to improve the precision of the answer.
Thanks!

Comment: is there is a way to convert matrix A to reduce row echelon form? then it is rather simple

Comment: @pyCthon No, i wanted a more direct method, which is why instead of coding the entire thing, i used the library functions.

Comment: I agree this is something the library should support, I've searched the API and i'm not sure how to compute the null space as well. I would contact the developers and see what they suggest,  http://arma.sourceforge.net/contact.html

Comment: @pyCthon Thanks, I'll do that

Comment: @pyCthon do you have any updates about this question? :)

Answer (score 6):

In recent version of the armadillo library you can find the orthonormal basis of the null space of matrix using the `null()` function. See the documentation at http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#null. The functionality was added in version 5.400 (August 2015).